# Javascript Regex - Camel to File Case

Tags: javascript, regex

Anyone have a regex in javascript for converting:

someCamelCase into some-file-case

or

SomeCamelCase into some-file-case

??

If so, that would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can change case with a Regex. I'd try a standard loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a simple regexp to capture a lowercase letter contiguous to an uppercase one, insert a dash between both and make the result all lowercase.

For example:

```
function fileCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, "$1-$2").toLowerCase();
}

fileCase('SomeCamelCase'); // "some-camel-case"
fileCase('someCamelCase'); // "some-camel-case"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here. try this one.

```
"SomeCamelCase".replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(m){return '_' + m.toLowerCase();});
```

or as a function

```
function camelToHiphen(str){
    return str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(m){return '_' + m.toLowerCase();});
}
```

Comment: This returns "_some_camel_case". It might be a good idea to trim the first underscore from the string. Otherwise +1 it works.

Comment: Sorry 'bout that. haven't tested it. just built the code in my head. :)

Answer (score 0):

### Camel Case <=> Hyphen Case Conversion Methods:

> disclaimer : I do not condone
>   clobbering the String prototype in the
>   way that I have below.

This is a prototype method on string for doing camelCase to hyphen-case that will account for uppercase beginning characters.

```
String.prototype.camelToHyphen = function() {
  return this.replace(/((?!^)[A-Z])/g, '-$1').toLowerCase();
};
```

This solution was brought on by my search for the exact opposite.

```
String.prototype.hyphenToCamel = function() {
  return (/-[a-z]/g.test(this)) ? this.match(/-[a-z]/g).map(function(m, n){
    return m.replace(n, n.toUpperCase()[1]);
  }, this) : this.slice(0);
};
```

I figure these are common enough issues but I could not find anything immediately that summed them up in this way.